# Load wordpress template part after click a button

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is here any way to call a wordpress template part when user click on a button?

Actually I want to place a button named "details" in wordpress woocommerce products page. When user click on it they will redirect in a custom template part.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this with separate page loads via a rewrite endpoint. This will send a request to the server for each button click, and you'd have to format the links yourself to append the endpoint to the permalink, not sure if that meets your requirements.

First register the endpoint for the page post type:

```
function wpa_view_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'view', EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa_view_endpoint' );
```

Now for each page like:

`http://example.com/some-page/`
You can also have URLs like:

`http://example.com/some-page/view/list/`
The value of view will be available in your template via `get_query_var`:

`$view = get_query_var( 'view' );`
Then you can display whatever markup based on that value.

You could also filter the loading of page templates and load a separate template for each view that way:

```
function wpa_view_template( $template = '' ){
    global $wp_query;
    if( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['view'] ) ) {
        $template = locate_template( $wp_query->query_vars['view'] . '.php', false );
    }
    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpa_view_template' );
```

So for the example:

```
http://example.com/some-page/view/list/
```

This filter will load the template list.php instead of your default page template.

Comment: I can not make any new page in website :-( Need to pull some information from a template part when user click on details of each product

Comment: I do not understand this?